# Using nodejs's Forever to output console.logs to screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I just discovered that my nodejs app keeps crashing, so I've used `forever app.js` to start my app and have it automatically restarted when it crashes.

**Problem:** Now my app outputs alot of useful information as it runs via `console.log` and `util.log`. I used to use `screen` to run the node app, but now that I'm using forever to run the nodejs app, I can no longer see all the outputs.

Is there any way to see all the output from the nodejs app in realtime?

Comment: Just open up the logfile in tail, but if you need to view the output realtime it suggests you shouldn't be using forever (i.e. you're debugging).

Comment: i output some info so I can monitor number of jobs, number of connected clients at any time which is very useful for me for monitoring the load and to determine if I should add more clients or whether half the client pool has crashed. I suppose that to do what I want to do, I should have a 'master client' that connects to this nodejs server to receive the debug info? Or is there another method

Comment: And I'm running forever while I'm in dev so I can learn how to use it and discover any pitfalls I'm going to encounter when going live. I see no reason why it's 'bad' to use forever while in dev.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can watch a logfile live by using this shell-command.

```
 tail -f /path/to/logfile
```

Not sure if this is what you needed.

Comment: Sounds like it may be what I need, I'll need to get back to my system to try out `tail`. From a quick google search, tail just shows the last X number of lines in a file, but does it update in real time?

Comment: `-f` flag will do what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any other way to direct console.log output to screen? I am using a IBM Bluemix Cloud where I can't ssh into the server and see the tail. But I can see the "console.log"s if they can be displayed on the screen.

Comment: @skjindal93 wondering the same, but as no one is replying, I guess not.

Answer (score 37):

Directly with forever command :

```
forever logs app.js -f
```

It shows in realtime output of your application and forever logs (shows detected changes & restart messages).

Comment: It works, just start your process: forever start app.js, then forever logs app.js -f

Comment: Definitely this is the correct answer. This is the correct use of Forever to output log files.

Answer (score 15):

**Simplest way to go is**

Run :

```
forever logs // will give you list of log files
forever logs 0 -f // then just provide the index of log
```

Answer (score 3):

If you pass the `--help` flag to Forever you'll see this example:

```
forever -o out.log -e err.log my-script.js
```

`-o` and `-e` define the stdout and stderr log files.

```
-o  OUTFILE      Logs stdout from child script to OUTFILE
-e  ERRFILE      Logs stderr from child script to ERRFILE
```

Forever seems a little overkill for development. Give [Supervisor](https://github.com/petruisfan/node-supervisor) a shot and see if you like it better:

```
npm install -g supervisor
supervisor app.js
```

Answer (score 1):

I am running nodejs on AWS EC2 instance and this worked for me. 
Note: logs are accessible if you are root owner. So first use **sudo su** then

```
forever -a -o out.log -e err.log yourServerApp.js
```

It will tail console log (in case you track event messages from log) and error log. I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

```
linux : tail -f /path/to/logfile.log
windows : enter PowerShell -> Get-Content /path/to/logfile.log -Wait -Tail 1000
```