# How to bring a nodejs app started with forever to foreground?

Tags: node.js, linux, forever

I have a nodejs app that will output to the terminal. But when the app is started with forever "**forever start server.js**", nothing will output on the terminal, this is ok and expected.

Is there a way to bring the forever process to foreground in order to see the app's outputs to terminal  ?

I know where forever stores the logs. My app displays output in a "dashboard" style. Looking at the logs is not what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does forever store console.log output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021186/where-does-forever-store-console-log-output)

Comment: Then probably https://stackoverflow.com/q/10368973/3001761

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "bring the forever process to foreground"? Did you press the **CTRL + Z**?

Comment: @Antz **CTRL-Z** works perfectly when starting the application using: **node server.js**. But I have no control on jobs when using forever. My application outputs a "**htop**" like dashboard. I'm trying to bring the dashboard back to the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On linux, you could use [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) it keeps a virtual terminal and allow a backgrounding and foregrounding with user interaction and page formatting.